# jQuery - Copy / move text from select list to textarea

Tags: jquery, select, textarea

The img below describes what I am trying to do:

[image: Copy text from select list to textarea]

So when an entry from the select list is selected and button "Copy" is pressed, it will add an < li > element to the text area.

Any ideas, resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the button is clicked you can just read the selected option using jQuery and add it to the text area.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectBox">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>

<input id="copyBtn" type="button" value="copy" />

<textarea id="output">
    This is some intro text
</textarea>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#copyBtn").click(function(){
    var selected = $("#selectBox").val();
    $("#output").append("\n * " + selected);
});​
```

You can only add text to a textarea, it doesn't render html tags (so a list inside it won't work). I used `\n` to create newlines.

**Fiddle**

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy7rT/6/)

Answer (score 3):

I give you an example, simple one:

HTML code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="options">
    <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="item4">Item 4</option>
    <option value="item5">Item 5</option>
</select>


<button id="test">Copy</button>

<textarea cols="25" rows="5" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", function(){
        $("#textarea").empty(); //to empty textarea content
        $(".options option:selected").each(function(){
           $("#textarea").append("* "+$(this).text()+ "\n");
        }); 
    });       
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pf5CU/

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/pf5CU/1/

Answer (score 3):

link http://jsfiddle.net/pf5CU/43/

use this

```
       $("#textarea2").append('<option>'+$(this).text()+'</option>'); 
        $('option:selected', "#textarea").remove();
```

Comment: this one has 2 select boxes and allows to move items between them

Comment: in case you also want to copy the option value, use `$("#textarea2").append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">'+$(this).text()+'</option>');`