# How do I create two different textareas with muliple items clickable to move between the two textareas?

Tags: html, select, textarea

I have been looking around for a couple days now and haven't found the answer.  I did see this: [jQuery - Copy / move text from select list to textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365049/jquery-copy-move-text-from-select-list-to-textarea) which I already did, but then the problem is what if the after copying the selected drop down item to go into the text area you change your mind and want to send it back or get rid of it?

I'm not sure if it's best to use two  tags or if I should use textareas.  This is what I have for the field on the left:

```
<select size="10" name="options" variable="#available options" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

And then when options are selected and the button is clicked they are added to a list and my textarea on the right reflects that list.  Should I also make the area on the right a selectable drop down similar to the one with all my options?  If I do that, then how to I get it to reflect only the options I have clicked?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense.  It's my first time posting here and I'm not a programmer (but learning).  Thanks in advance!